# information on how to translate the component for joomla

Tags: joomla

where can I find the italian translations of the civicrm component for joomla?
or how can I do the translation in Italian?

- List item

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM has its own setting to set default language. To configure CiviCRM to use an translation:

- Download the translations distribution -
  civicrm--l10n.tar.gz - from the CiviCRM downloads page. This
  tarball contains all files for the latest available translations.
- Uncompress the tarball and you will see a directory called civicrm,
  containing two subdirectories called l10n and sql. The l10n directory
  contains a set of sub-directories named using their local codes.
  (Example: the Italian translation files will located in
  /civicrm/l10n/it_IT).
- Copy this l10n directory, together with all its subdirectories into
  your CiviCRM codebase root directory.(note if creating the l10n
  folder manually it should be ell-ten-n, not capital-I-ten-n)

  ```
  For Joomla this would be site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm. So if you wanted the it_IT language it would look like this site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/l10n/it_IT/
  ```

**To enable the default language**

- Login to CiviCRM (as a user with "administer CiviCRM permissions").
- Go to Administer » Localization » Languages, Currency, Locations.
- You should now be able to see and select all the localization options
  in the Default Language and drop-down menu. If you don't, and instead
  can just see the default 'English (United States)' option, check the
  preceding steps as the drop-down options are set by the directories
  under your l10n directory. Also be sure to confirm that the l10n
  directory is correctly named as l10n (that is: el-ten-en and not
  eye-ten-en).

HTH

Pradeep